# How does this R function for the Sieve of Eratosthenes work?

Tags: r

I just started learning R, and was looking at a block of code that found prime numbers with the Sieve of Eratosthenes, up to some number n:

```
sieve <- function(n) {
  if (n < 2) return(NULL)
  a <- rep(T, n)
  a[1] <- F
  for(i in seq(n)) {
    if (a[i]) {
      j <- i * i
      if (j > n) return(which(a))
      a[seq(j, n, by=i)] <- F
    }
  }
}
```

The code works, but I don't understand how. I'm particularly confused by what a[seq(j, n, by=i)] is doing. I wrote comments on the code to show what I believe it does so far:

```
n=10
sieve <- function(n) {
  if (n < 2) return(NULL) #ignore inputs that don't return anything
  a <- rep(T, n) #TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE 
  a[1] <- F ##to ignore 1? #FALSE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
  for(i in seq(n)) {
    if (a[i]) { #i.e., for all values but 1
      j <- i * i #4 9 16 25...
      if (j > n) return(which(a))
      a[seq(j, n, by=i)] <- F
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Forget the code -- do you understand the logic of the sieve itself? If not, that is the place to start (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes is a good read). The code itself is a reasonably straightforward implementation of the core algorithm.

Comment: Tangentially -- using `T` and `F` as abbreviations for `TRUE` and `FALSE` is considered risky. See https://www.r-bloggers.com/r-tip-avoid-using-t-and-f-as-synonyms-for-true-and-false/   (R Bloggers itself is a good resource for anyone learning R).

Comment: try using `debug(sieve)`  followed by `sieve(7)` so that you can step through the code a line at a time (and print out the value of any object you're curious about)

Comment: Your comment in `j <- i * i #4 9 16 25...` contains a misapprehension. `j` will never take on the value 16, for example. The point is that once the sieve identifies e.g. `5` as a prime then `5*5` is the first composite multiple of `5` which hasn't (unlike `10, 15, 20`) already been identified as composite.

Comment: John Coleman is right in the first comment; I thought that the Sieve of Eratosthenes used a different algorithm and reading the Wikipedia page clarified matters. Thank you for your help!